# Cumulate word count by Flink timeWindow using Scala

Tags: twitter, stream, apache-flink

I have the twitter streaming API and I am retrieving tweets from there.
I also have a list of desired words that I want to take into account.

What I want to do is to store to my Cassandra dataBase always the most accurate value corresponding to how many times the word was used on the day.

I was thinking of using window functions to consolidade the results each 5 seconds and then writing this consolidate value on the database.

I don't know if this is the best approach. 
If this is the best approach, I tried to do a simple example following the documentation, but it doesn't group the words each 5 seconds.

```
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

    val counts =
      env.fromElements("foo bar test test baz foo", "yes no no yes", "hi hello hi hello")
      .flatMap { _.toLowerCase.split("\\W+") filter { _.nonEmpty } }
      .filter(word => Words.listOfWords.contains(word) || Words.listOfWords2.contains(word))
      .map { (_, 1) }
      .keyBy(0)
      .timeWindow(Time.seconds(5)).sum( 1)

    counts.print()
    env.execute("test-code")

  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by 5 to 5 seconds ??

Comment: each 5 seconds, i've updated the question ;)

Comment: Okay, Could You also explain why do You check twice for the same thing in `filter` ?

Comment: was a mistype, they are different things being searched on the list, I've updated

Answer (score 1):

Well, currently it will not work, because You are creating the `DataStream` from elements, which is not the best idea for windowing, because You won't really have a 5 seconds of the runtime to create more than one window, so all of the messages will go to the same window. But, if you would run this on the actual Twitter API, this should generally group the items into windows properly.

Comment: Ok, I see. But the best is to group and then add this grouped value to the one in database or is to update the database each element?

Comment: I am not sure what are You asking about. But generally the decision whether to update the database for each element or to group elements in windows and updated them when the window is emitted, depends on the use case. Generally, if You can I would suggest to use windows as this will decrease the number of updates in the database greatly which will result in better performance overall.